# Part of sum inequality to number of terms

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose you have a series
 $$ S=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$ and rearrange the terms such that, $$ a_1\geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_l \geq a_i\geq 0 $$ for all $$ i > l$$, then it should be obvious that $$ \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_l}{S}\geq \frac{l}{n}$$ How would one go about proving this? Using upper and underestimates won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: first rearrange your inequality to $\displaystyle \frac{S}{n} \leqslant \frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_l}{l}$. Then note that

$$\frac{S}{n} = \frac{l}{n} \cdot \frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_l}{l} + \left( 1-\frac{l}{n} \right) \cdot \frac{a_{l+1} + \ldots + a_n}{n-l}$$

which is a [weighted arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Mathematical_definition) of two numbers, where the first $\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_l}{l}$ is bigger.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So because the first term $$ \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_l}{l}$$ is bigger the weight of $$l/n \leq \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_l}{S}$$  must be lower than the above equation?

Comment: @JordyMolenaar No, I didn't mean that. I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: oh I see now, because the second fraction is smaller than the first it will only make the arithmetic mean smaller. I got confused with $$\frac{S}{l}$$, instead of $$\frac{S}{n}$$, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_l}{S}\ge \frac{l}{n} \Rightarrow $$
$$\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_l}{l}\ge \frac{a_1+\cdots +a_l+a_{l+1}+\cdots +a_n}{l+(n-l)} \Rightarrow$$
$$(n-l)(a_1+\cdots +a_l)\ge l(a_{l+1}+\cdots +a_n)$$
Now the LHS:
$$(n-l)(a_1+\cdots +a_l)\ge (n-l)(\underbrace{a_l+\cdots +a_l}_{l})$$
and the RHS:
$$l(\underbrace{a_{l+1}+\cdots a_{l+1}}_{n-l})\ge l(a_{l+1}+\cdots +a_n)$$
Hence:
$$(n-l)la_l\ge l(n-l)a_{l+1} \Rightarrow$$
$$a_l\ge a_{l+1}.$$